# How to run CasperJS script without using PHP exec or shell_exec

Tags: javascript, php, shell, casperjs

I have a CasperJS script in which its results needs to be captured in PHP. For that I had to use PHP's `exec()` or `shell_exec()` functions. But recently I got to know that enabling command line execution on server is risky and not safe. So how am I supposed to run my CasperJS script without using either of those functions in PHP?

***PS***:
To be more precise, how to use CasperJS on web browser, like processing a web form with PHP and return an output derived from the CasperJS without touching exec or shell_exec to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS (or SlimerJS). It can use all the features PhantomJS provides which includes the [Web Server Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/). The idea would be to run a single CasperJS instance which your PHP script can query through HTTP.

You can start a CasperJS script at system startup or through a cron job (and restarting when it crashes). You can then query it through local http requests.

CasperJS script:

```
var webserver = require('webserver');
var server = webserver.create();
var service = server.listen(8080, function(request, response) {
    var casper = require('casper').create({
        exitOnError: false,
        onError: function(msg, backtrace){
            response.statusCode = 500;
            response.write('ERROR: ' + msg + "\n" + JSON.stringify(backtrace));
            response.close();
        }
    });

    casper.start(yourURL, function(){
        // TODO: do something
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.write('something');
        response.close();
    }).run(function(){
        // this function is necessary to prevent exiting the whole script
    });
});
```

And in PHP you can then use something like [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve the response:

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8080/");
```

Things to look out for:

- Configure your machine in such a way that the port PhantomJS is running on is not accessible from outside.
- If you're using a cron job approach, write a pid file to make sure not to start another instance.
- The web server module only supports 10 concurrent requests. If your system exceeds those, you will need to create a pool of multiple CasperJS (PhantomJS) processes.
- The pages of a single CasperJS (PhantomJS) process all share the same session just like in any normal browser. If you want to isolate them from one another, then you need to run a CasperJS (PhantomJS) process for every request.

Comment: I am thinking of a way to use casper js on web browser, not only using executing by a cron. Something processing a web form and return an output derived from the casper js.

Comment: I guess I haven't made that clear. CasperJS would run continuously in the background and receive connections from your PHP script. The cron part is only there in case CasperJS crashes so it can be restarted.

Answer (score 0):

You do the usual little square dance.

1. Run your PHP thing, capturing input, producing a *job* configuration.
2. Put that *job* in your DB, get it out with CRON.
3. Process it with *whatever*, put the result in different DB table, or in the filesystem.
4. Mark your *job* as 'done', so your user-facing PHP can poll for that status periodically, and present the user with the end result when it's done.

If you're doing this because you know what attack vector an `exec()` exposes in your app, and can't live with that -- that's alright.

But if you're doing this because you're scared of "not even sure what", then don't. You'll make it worse.

Good luck.
:)